# Convert non-ascii characters to unicode escape sequence

Tags: postgresql, unicode-escapes

Is it any function in postgres sql to convert non ascii characters to unicode e.g. polish letter `ż` to `\u017C`?

I've tried to use encode and convert_from build postgres functions but without any results.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ASCII()` coupled with `to_hex()`. Finally the `concat()` will get you your required unicode.

```
postgres=# SELECT ascii('ż');
 ascii 
-------
   380
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT CHR(380);
 chr 
-----
 ż
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT to_hex(ascii('ż'));
 to_hex 
--------
 17c
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT concat('\u0', to_hex(ascii('ż')));
 concat 
--------
 \u017c
(1 row)
```

For additional characters, you may have to improvise using `substring()`

```sql
SELECT concat('\u0', to_hex(ascii('życie')), substring('życie' from 2 for 4));
   concat   
------------
 \u017cycie
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only works for one char, how to do the same for strings e.g. 'życie' to '\u017Cycie' ?

Comment: This should do for now.

```SELECT concat('\u0', to_hex(ascii('życie')), substring('życie' from 2 for 4));```